# Xcode UITableViewCell duplicate changes position and dimension of included objects

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, constraints

Xcode Version 11.5 (11E608c). I have a UITableView with multiple sections. Inside a section, I duplicated (copy/paste) a cell (including constraints) to just below. This new cell's included label leading bound is 8 points further left than the original one, hence not vertically aligned as you can see on the screenshot below. This is definitely not what I want.

[image]

However when I run the project in the simulator and actual device, the left bounds of Download Period 3 and 4 are properly aligned.

Xcode view dimensions of the Download Period labels are:
Download Period 3: `X=16, Y=11, Width=324, Height=22`
Download Period 4: `X=8, Y=11, Width=333, Height=22`

Except above, all data from Identity, Attributes and Size inspectors are identical for both cells (Download Period 3 and 4).

If I adjust the values from Download period 4 to the ones of Download Period 3, I get a `Misplaced views` warning for Download Period 4:
`Expected x=8, width=333`
`Actual x=16, width=324`

There is no code involved which might interfere with the layout.

Here the constraints I use (Download Period 4 is shown, identical for Download Period 3):

[image]

This could be anything. From Xcode bug to stupid mistake at my end. Bottom line is, that I don't find the source of the problem. I would like to understand why a duplication of a cell changes dimensions and position of included objects, and why the storyboard shows a misalignment versus correct alignment on simulator and actual device. I can't see what's wrong here.

**----- UPDATE 05.06.2020 14:00 UTC -----**

I checked the Main.storyboard xml file, extracted the relevant parts for Download Period 3 and 4 into separate files, and ran the diff command. Except the ids, all was identical!

After manually adjusting the Download Period 4 to x=16, width=324, I see the dashed orange line at the leading bound. This means my constraints don't match my actual view. It seems (?!) that the bounds of either Superview or Margins have changed from one cell to another. AFAIK this is not possible though?

[image]

On top, I noticed that all cells below Download Period 4 (even through new sections) have the same problem. Leading/trailing bounds on Superview + margin have 8 points more right & left (so 16 in total).

**----- UPDATE 06.06.2020 15:30 UTC -----**

Further tests - When I change the Layout Margins of Download Period 4 Table View Cell manually (to `Fixed`), the label bounds are correct, no orange dashed lines in storyboard, no `Misplaced views` warning messages, storyboard presentation identical to simulator and actual device presentation. In summary ... all exactly how it should be!

As a reminder, the issue starts between the two Table View Cells holding Download Period 3 and 4 (see screenshot above). Assuming the problem comes from wrong margins, that's what I did:

Table View Cell (for Download Period 3 - default, not changed)
Size inspector
Layout Margins : `Automatic`

Table View Cell (for Download Period 4 - changed)
Size inspector
Layout Margins : `Fixed`
`Left   : 16` (was 8)
`Top    : 8`.
`Bottom : 8`.
`Right  : 16` (was 8)

This confirms my initial assumption that the margins changed somehow between both Table View Cells.

Is this a known bug?
Is there some kind of cache Xcode is using to generate the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to not copy and paste the cell but rather drag and drop one from the library and add constraints from scratch. Or you can select the copied cell and clear all constraints and add them again.

Comment: The copy/paste feature is implemented in Xcode, so it should work. I have quite some objects inside the cell, therefore I prefer not to implement all from the scratch. Besides this, have a look at my update (05.06.2020 14:00 UTC). I compared the xml tags from both cells. All is 100% identical. Regarding clearing and adding the constraints ... that's what I did already at the very beginning. No joy ...